How to grant Lightroom full access to QNAP NAS at MacOS?
I have a strange problem.
I have QNAP NAS running on local network at 192.168.86.91. When I connect to the NAS via QNAP Qfinder I can map a volume to Mac Finder. There I have an access to NAS files. I can save data to NAS and remove files.
Now to the actual problem. When I open Lightroom, it says I have read-only access to the QNAP NAS.
I just can't figure out why Lightroom can't save data to the NAS when I can do it by myself via Mac Finder.
What I've tried already is that I checked from the Mac settings that Lightroom should have full access to everything.

Is you LR catalog on your internal drive (it should be)?  Have you copied your photos to the NAS? What steps did you do before getting the read-only message in LR? Have you tried with an SMB share on the NAS (rather then what Qfinder does)?

My LR catalog is in the internal drive. I've copied my photos to the NAS. This is what I did today:
I tried to access the NAS via Mac Finder. The SMB connection was successful.  (This time I didn't use Qfinder.) I was able to save a file to the NAS and remove it. I opened LR and it said the NAS was online. However, saving XMP files to the NAS is still not possible.

I don't know anything much about Qfinder, but I am suspicious that LR is looking for photos with Qfinder file locations and not SMB share file locations. Have you asked QNAP support or forum?  Otherwise, sadly, wait for a QNAP expert to assist here.

Thanks. I made a ticket to QNAP support. Let's have them to look into this.
